# how calculate from endate amount of days excluding holidays

Tags: excel-formula

Hi does anybody has good idea about how calculating backwards day from end date with respect to workdays?

Lets say we know Deadline 30thNovember activity to be done. We know that we need 20 working days for activity to be performed. So how can we calculate latest start date for activity in respect to saturdays/sundays, if not Vacationdates or holidays?

I.e. Backwards logic of =WORKDAY(A2,B2)

Answer (score 0):

Screenshot/[here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j9-UKhOZDJLmbl_AUc?e=PTz8OY) refer:

[image: Screenshot]

```
=B13+B6-SUM(1*(B9:B10>=B13)*(B9:B10<=B13+B6))
```

Notes:

- Falls down if holiday coincides with new end date or start date